# Remove doubles distorts mesh aspect in object mode (still good in edit mode)

Tags: modeling

when i apply remove doubles there is a destroyed mesh aspect on object mode (pressing z) and the mesh is perfectly fine one i go in edit mode, is it a display issue or im i doing something wrong? its the same mesh on these pictures, left on object, right on edit mode

Edit: the mesh looks fine on object mode as well when if i save it to .obj and delete-reload it.  but the problem persists when i save the whole scene

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be correct. By default Blender displays wireframes based on the angle of the faces connected by a given edge. In order to have blender show all edges you have to check *"Draw all Edges"*.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perfect. thanks a lot!